# Can I grab information which users have set to private by using Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, private

If the user has set the information (e.g. movies, books, TV) to private instead of public, can I still grab such data by using the [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API)?

Comment: I hope not.  That would mean it wasn't private, no?

Answer (score 0):

If you request the appropriate [extended permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) like `user_activities`, etc then the API will return you that info for the current user regardless of privacy setting.  If you try to get info from friends by asking for `friends_activities` etc then the privacy settings do come into play and if the friend restricts you from seeing that information, then you will not be able to see it.  You also won't be able to see that info if the user opted out of the Facebook App Platform entirely.